# Trying to identify a mushroom found in my backyard

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I'm new at trying to describe mushrooms though I will try my best.

- subtract from growth : grass
- color : light grey/brown then a faded orange at the top
- gill color is also light brown
- ovate shape
- believe the gills attachment is adnate
- I think that this mushroom could be part of the coprinopsis family and found that the coprinopsis martini is pretty similar
  -Also could possibly be a humpback inkcap
- location is southern Georgia (USA)
- extremely delicate, it ripped very easily
  [image: Image of the mushrooms I'm trying to identify]

Comment: Were they growing in open area or in shade? Where they growing in a circular pattern or randomly? Over a wide area or clustered together?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, this is definitely a species of Coprinopsis, as you said. However, when it comes to this and related genera I find that the great diversity of species makes it pretty hard to pin down IDs. Coprinopsis martinii/acuminata like you suggested indeed seem pretty promising appearance-wise, but like I said you'll find this to be the case with many species of this genus, and neither seem very biogeographically relevant to Georgia. Try using iNaturalist to search the area for Coprinopsis species and narrow down your search from there.